# seperate tasks to publish binaries in addition to publishLocal in sbt

Tags: sbt, publish

```
  publishArtifact in(Compile, packageSrc) := false
  publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
```

With above settings in build.sbt, publishLocal only publish binaries.
Kindly suggest a workaround example, where publishLocal can be used to publish all 3 artifacts (binary, source and docs). And a new task (for example publishBinaryToLocal) can be used to publish binary  file only. Tried below code, but it's not working :-

```
lazy val publishBinaryToLocal = taskKey[Unit]("publish only binary to local")

publishBinaryToLocal := {
  publishArtifact in(Compile, packageSrc) := false
  publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
  publishLocal.value
}
```

Comment: In the body of `publishBinaryToLocal`, surely you mean to set those settings to `true`, not `false`? Regardless, it still won't work. But I think the "Updating State in a task " section of the sbt doc might be what you want: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Build-State.html#Updating+State+in+a+task